# Using like with where clause for deleting in android

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, where-clause, sql-like

I am developing an android app, where I wan to delete a row based on a where clause accompanied with a like clause too. Below is the code what I have tried,

```
            String where = "numberp Like '%''"+phonetounbold+"'";
            String[] whereArgs = null;

            delcount = db.delete("NUMBERLIST", where, whereArgs);
```

In the above table I want to delete a row from NUMBERLIST table , which contains phonetounbold like string from numberp column. But the above query  is not working. Where am I going wrong with the syntax. Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the "where" clause to

`String where = "numberp LIKE '%"+phonetounbold+"'";`

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing using the raw SQLiteDatabase interface, not the content provider, you can use [execSQL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String%29) method directly:

```
database.execSQL("delete from numberlist where numberp like '%xyz%'")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String where = "numberp Like '%" + phonetounbold + "'";
```